# 'Code inserting' versus 'inserting of code'

Tags: prepositions, clauses

I found that English language allows using of `object - verb` instead of `verb - of - object` to say probably the same. For example

> code inserting

instead of

> inserting of code

or so. And my question is, if those ways are really equal - or if is there any difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are functionally equivalent. Note that "inserting" is not really a noun, it is a gerund. That means the verb's progressive form functions as a noun. So you have two nouns there, the first one functioning as an adjective. These are sometimes called attributive nouns.

Often people will rewrite gerunds to avail themselves of a "legitimate" noun, if one is available:

> code insertion
>   insertion of code

But that is just a matter of style and taste.

Note that the shorter version may seem too colloquial for some who believe that brevity is somehow ungrammatical, but unless you wind up with a really outlandish construction using the attributive noun template (I can't think of any offhand), you really can't go wrong with the shortened form.

Comment: +.9 ... I'd add that *VERBing OBJ* is also acceptable, and usually preferable to *OBJ VERBing*.

Comment: Hmmm, @StoneyB, Robusto. Good advice, but the assertion about *inserting* seems wrong to me. *The inserting of code*, *The code insertion*, *The haphazard insertion of code* etc, etc. Doesn't look like a gerund to me. It looks like a noun. Now if it was *inserting code*, that would be a different matter.

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm ... I'm not sure I can go along with *your rigidly reassigning* PoS on the basis of syntactic role. After all, the categories *gerund* and *participle* (and *gerund-participle*!) are by definition ambivalent.

Comment: @StoneyB ? Gerunds are verbs and participles are verbs. But nouns aren't. Verbs don't have determiners, nouns do. Verbs can have objects, nouns can't. But even if we try and wonk that (which is ok with me), it's now even odder to  say that *inserting* isn't a noun, it's a gerund in these cases.

Comment: @Araucaria What's *reassigning* in my previous comment, with  determiner *your* but taking an object and modified by an adverb?

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, yep, my balls up. Determiner won't do the trick. 'Article' or 'determinative' would have been a better choice. Yours is a verb, I reckon. But that's a bit by the by. What I'm saying is that it's odd to assert that *inserting* isn't a noun here.

Comment: @Araucaria: The proof is in the eating. It's the doing of a job that's important. I handled the feeding of the animals. Etc.

Comment: @Robusto Yes, in those examples, we'd uncontroversially regard the words ending in *-ing* as nouns, as opposed to gerunds/verbs etc. (Nice post, btw)